# Prevent overlapping properties when spreading multiple objects in a new one

Tags: typescript, eslint

Let's say we have

```
x = {a:65, b:634, c:74};
y = {o:453, e:5342, g:543}
z = {o:453, e:5342, b:543}


// Doing this should be okay
const both = {...x, ...y}

// However, when doing this:
const both = {...x, ...z}
```

I need it to show some error like "Property b cannot be reassigned" or whatever, just don't let it compile. Any suggestions?

Edit:
I know I can easily write a function to combine the objects and conditionally raise an exception but the point is that I need to do such kind of checking before runtime. It would be very helpful if it can be done using typescript, eslint or any trick that can check for such condition before runtime...

Comment: You'll have to write your own code to check the objects involved before combining them. Overwriting properties is allowed in JavaScript.

Comment: What should the output be if overriding is not allowed?

Comment: I know I can easily write my own function to combine them and conditionally raise an exception but I need to do it before runtime. I'm hoping it can be done with typescript somehow or maybe using the const keyword or something...

Comment: Or maybe using eslint... I don't mind as long as it's before runtime

Comment: I mean if you already know the keys just use typescript and make sure each object has its own type. That would prevent any overlapping keys.

Comment: No, I don't. Let's say the keys of `x` will be set by one developer, while the keys of `y` will be set by another developer. That's why it needs to let them know if there's a conflict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to make a simple utility function..

You can get the keys of each, and use includes to make sure the key doesn't already exists in the other keys.

eg.

```js
const x = {a:65, b:634, c:74};
const y = {o:453, e:5342, g:543};
const z = {o:453, e:5342, b:543};

function join(a,b) {
  const ak = Object.keys(a);
  const bk = Object.keys(b);
  for (const k of bk)
    if (ak.includes(k)) 
      throw new Error(`key ${k} cannot be re-assigned`);
  return {...a, ...b};
}

console.log(join(x, y));
console.log(join(x, z));
```

If you wish to do some checking at designtime using Typescript, one idea is to get the intersection types of the 2 objects, if the intersection is never, we could then make a fake type that returns true, or false if an overlap.  If you then try and assign true to this type and there is an overlap you will get an error.  The fake assignment on a good bundler should also remove this fake statement.

eg.

```
const x = {a:65, b:634, c:74};
const y = {o:453, e:5342, g:543};
const z = {o:453, e:5342, b:543};

type NoOverlap<A extends object, B extends object> = 
  keyof A & keyof B extends never ? true : false;

const _dummy1:NoOverlap<typeof x, typeof y> = true;
const _dummy2:NoOverlap<typeof x, typeof z> = true; //this will error.
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDA3gQwFwDYCsAaGAI2wGYAWA4DAdjIF8BuAKFElgE8lUQMycSCAUwz8yAJgIBzEWRKMW4aDABeXFDz4CYw0RKIy5zJlHYAHQTAByIAPIA3QQCcANmlMAeAILa4UQWAATCBgQQgArQWAoAgAhHz9A4NCIqIA%20LiYYGABrQXYQADMYbwAyHLzCmDjBX38gmDBBB0cYAH4YKEcAVwsMGAK0ZwhBI1YlAH0AroBbafYARgxreydXDxNzSrgCDcFK9nTkTp7mMdhJmbmxJdtmtfddrZ2zPaLlQ47ukaYmIA)

Comment: But the main point is that I need to do it before runtime... Anything with typescript, eslint or any tool that can do it before actually running the code?

Comment: @Menas  I've added a Typescript variant that might help.

Comment: Heyyy!! How did you do this? I love it and it seems to work but I'm not sure I understand it.. Did you just create a function using type annotation  0_0 ?

Comment: Is there anyway I can customize the error message tho? rather than `Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'.` ?

Comment: @Menas  You could maybe alter the tenary, so instead of returning  `? true : false` you could do `? true : 'Overlapped'`, you would then get `Type 'true' is not assignable to type '"Overlapped"'.`  Not sure if that helps, but it would hopefully give the Dev's a clue that it's an error down to overlapping keys.

Comment: @Kaith It's hard to find people so good with typescript... Can I please have any contact information of yours, just in case?

Comment: Oh!! there are people on SO with way better TS skills than me.. :)  But if you want me to look at any in the future, if you tag me on any posts, including this one, it should appear in my inbox.

Comment: Ummm, I'm not sure how that works. Will I have to tag you by your profile serial number like @6870228 ? I believe display names here are not unique identifiers. So if you're not already in the post it probably wouldn't know which Keith :/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with n arguments:

```
function combineNoOverwrite(...args) {
  return args.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    for (var key in cur) {
      if (cur.hasOwnProperty(key) && !acc.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        acc[key] = cur[key];
      } else {
        throw new Error(`key ${key} cannot be re-assigned`);
      }
    }
    return acc;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following.

```
function combine(x, y) {
    const array = Object.keys(x).concat(Object.keys(y))
    if (array.length != [...new Set(array)].length) {
        console.error("Error: Duplicate Key")
        return
    } 
    return {...x, ...y}
}
```